# No test bundle found error only happening on one machine

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode9

I have several machines configured as Jenkins slaves, and having an issue while launching unit tests on one of them:

```
2018-08-22 10:23:28.441732+0200 xctest[4446:121482] *** Assertion failure in void _XCTestMain(XCTestConfiguration *__strong)(), /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/XCTest_Sim/XCTest-14100/Sources/XCTestFramework/Harness/XCTestMain.m:62
2018-08-22 10:23:28.443094+0200 xctest[4446:121482] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'No test bundle found at file:///Users/jenkins/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestProject-ggsxrowotsoemlhfxrnygnxavshz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/testprojecttests.xctest/'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001111dc1e6 __exceptionPreprocess + 294
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000110871031 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001111e1472 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 98
    3   Foundation                          0x00000001101d364f -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInFunction:file:lineNumber:description:] + 165
    4   XCTest                              0x000000011077daea _XCTestMain + 761
    5   xctest                              0x000000010fe042a4 main + 571
    6   libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000117d9b955 start + 1
    7   ???                                 0x0000000000000005 0x0 + 5
)
```

This happens with every iOS project I try to test, an ONLY on one of my slaves, so this should not be a project configuration issue, as cloning the same project and launching tests works fine on my other machines. In addition, it happens no matter if I launch tests from Jenkins or directly from the machine itself, by either using `xcodebuild test` command or Xcode test button.

I have tried to launch tests from a couple of Xcode versions (9.2 and 9.4.1) with the same result, uninstalled both and installed 9.4.1 again, cleaned the Build Folder, and also removed the Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData folder with no success so far.

Does anyone know what can I be missing and how to fix this issue?

Comment: Have you found an solution for this ?

Comment: @mmdumi Unfortunately not

Comment: I ended up removing anything Developer related from /Library/Developer and ~/Libray/Developer and Xcode and all caches. After reinstall everything worked correctly

Comment: @mmdumi I think I only tried removing everything from ~/Libray/Developer, not /Library/Developer, so I will try to do that. Let's hope it works. Thanks!!